# How to read encrypted responses in Loadrunner to fetch the data

Tags: loadrunner

I have one query - If application responses are not in readable than how to read the data

for Example : I need to  capture id and as per discuss , I got to know we need to import some library then only you can read the responses ... how to configure external jar in load runner and what piece of code we need to use so that it can read the responses using Jar

Answer (score 0):

See Data Format Extensions (DFE) in your LoadRunner training material or documentation